# Why does my AWS CodeBuild test report result in an 'Incomplete' status?

Tags: clojure, aws-codebuild, clojure.test

I am trying to understand why my JUnit XML report results in an Incomplete status on AWS CodeBuild.

The XML is produced by Kaocha, a Clojure test runner, through its `kaocha-junit-xml plugin`.

At the end of my test run, the XML is generated and then processed in the `UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS` phase which is where it does a calculation and that results in:

```
error processing report: [InvalidInputException: Test summary: status count cannot be negative]]
```

I do have multiple assertions per test, and thus there may be more than 1 failure per test.
To verify that I'm not having a buggy JUnit XML file, I have installed Jenkins and ran a couple of tests, which works and it does not end in an `Incomplete` Report status.

Note that the Test Run status is `Failed`, and only the Report status is `Incomplete`.

Answer (score 0):

Please review your `testsuite` property in the JUnit XML, e.g.

```
tests="1" failures="1" errors="1"
```

Here, the failures and errors are treated differently and this makes the errors = 2 (1+1) which is less than the number of tests (= 1) causing the negative status count (1-2).

I am not sure about the JUnit format, but if you can tweak it and make sure either failure or error is populated (not both), then this error ("status count cannot be negative") will not appear.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to have a look. If I understand correctly, failures are test failures/assertions, and errors are issues with or in the test, not relating to assertions.

I do happen to have multiple assertions in my test. It would be quite clunky to have to split a test up and run it n-times to test for something that has 1 result with n-checks.